# Problems since adding stripe api and coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

Hi So I recently added some coffeescript from a tutorial for card validations with stripe. I am getting an error i dont understand so if someone could give me any guidance it would be most appreciated.

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Devise::Sessions#new
SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:22: reserved word "function"
Extracted source (around line #6):
```

Site
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>

I have tried adding various things to the gemfile but to no joy, here is the relevant part of the application.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Site</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v2/" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => ENV["STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY"] %>
</head>
<body>
```

and here is the gemfile....

```
source 'https://code.stripe.com'
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass'

gem "paperclip"
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

gem 'devise'

gem 'figaro'

gem 'stripe'

gem 'therubyracer'

gem 'coffee-script-source'

group :production do 
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a problem with indentation, when deleting the coffeescript file and trying again it worked...